# LINQ to SQL class not showing in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, templates

I've run `/devenv installvstemplates` in VS2008 command prompt but no luck.  I think it's a project setting?

If I create a new project, I can add the Linq to SQL class, it appears.  But in my current website, it doesn't come up.

I can however use the LINQ to SQL class, I just copy and paste it over from one project to the other and it works fine.  The problem is trying to add a second one now, it conflicts with the first so I do need to add it properly via VS.

Why is this class template not showing for me?  Is there some setting I need to turn on or reference I need to add?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the target framework to 3.5 in the new project dialog, otherwise the LinQ to SQL classes template won't appear.

Comment: How do I change this for a website project?  Also, can I add it any other way?

Comment: You can do that by editing the website's project properties: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/06/29/net-framework-multitargeting-in-visual-studio-2008-aka-orcas.aspx

Comment: thanks!  I was able to change target framework from 2.0 to 3.5 via website > start options.  All working now!